# Salesforce Community Template issue

Tags: community, customer-community, community-builder, napili

I switched from Napili to Tabs & VFP.  When I am logged in as a Salesforce User, no issues... I see the tabs I have assigned to the Community and it looks fine.  However, when I login as a Community User it is still viewing Napili (via login-as, and when I login using their username/pw).  I've tried to switch back and forth again... make the Community inactive and Activate it again... any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your Administration Select Login | Registration and select Default for login page

[image]